# Android select query for search from edit text

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite

I want to enter any particular sport event in an edit text and by pressing the search button, its displays the particular sport event on a list view.

This is my code. I'm getting a null pointer exception. Anybody know why?

```
public Cursor searchRecords() { 
    return database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ TABLE_NAME +"WHERE _sportName  LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + etSearch.getText().toString() + "%"});
}
```

Comment: 11-04 19:10:51.301: E/AndroidRuntime(1681): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: post full error details and codes

Comment: 11-04 19:27:49.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1842): java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1):

Either your database member or etSearch member is null.

Also, you should put a space between your table name and the where clause.

Comment: Please check to make sure both database and etSearch are initialized to something other than null.  What line is logcat telling you is throwing the NPE?

Comment: new String[]{"%" + etSearch.getText().toString() + "%"}); this line is error

Comment: If you are getting a NullPointerException and it is on the line you  just specified, then etSearch is not initialized.  Have you somewhere else done a findViewById call to get the reference to your EditText and set it to etSearch?

Comment: ya i did that  searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.etSearch);

Comment: Shouldn't searchText be etSearch?

Comment: will try that and test

Comment: No searchText is a string variable whereas etSearch is the ID of the edittext.

Comment: Then I would change etSearch.getText().toString() to searchText.getText().toString()